# Reading only first integer from whole line in text file

Tags: c++, file-io

If have text file like this:

```
3       size of group
10     individual therapy time(min)
15     group therapy time(min)
25      new client probability percentage
500     individual therapy cost
300     group therapy cost
```

is there a way to just read first integer of text line and jump to other line?

What I have tried:

```
settingsFile >> groupSize >> trash >> trash >> trash;
settingsFile >> indTime >> trash >> trash >> trash;
settingsFile >> newClientProb >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash;
settingsFile >> indTherapyCost >> trash >> trash >> trash;
settingsFile >> groupTherapyCost >> trash >> trash >> trash;
```

And in my opinion, this is not a good way to read the text file, because if I delete one `trash` string from text file, the whole reading will fail.

Comment: Why not read by lines and extract the first value ?

Comment: I just noted that your example and code don't match up exactly. In the example, you have the line "group therapy time" which is missing in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ignore the rest of the line by using `std::getline` like that:

```
settingsFile >> groupSize;
std::getline(settingsFile, trash);
settingsFile >> indTime;
std::getline(settingsFile, trash);
settingsFile >> newClientProb;
std::getline(settingsFile, trash);
settingsFile >> indTherapyCost;
std::getline(settingsFile, trash);
settingsFile >> groupTherapyCost;
std::getline(settingsFile, trash);
```

An alternative is to read the file line by line into a temporary string variable, and then parsing the integer at the beginning of that string by utilizing `string_stream`, but this is kinda tedious.

If C++11 is available, this second step can be done easily with [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), ending up with a code like this (this time in a loop):

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(settingsFile, line); ) {
    int value = std::stoi(line);
    ...
}
```

Or introducing a new function `readIntLine`:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits>
int readIntLine(std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& input) {
    std::basic_string<CharT,Traits> line;
    std::getline(settingsFile, line);
    return std::stoi(line);
}
```

Then, it can be used like that:

```
groupSize = readIntLine(settingsFile);
indTime = readIntLine(settingsFile);
newClientProb = readIntLine(settingsFile);
indTherapyCost = readIntLine(settingsFile);
groupTherapyCost = readIntLine(settingsFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just read the integer and then `ignore()` the rest of the line:

```
using NL = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>;
while ((in >> value).ignore(NL::max(), '\n')) {
   ...
}
```

The use of `max()` is needed as this value says "as many characters as needed" rather than using some large upper limit. It may also be reasonable to package this logic as a manipulator:

```
std:: istream& ignl(std::istream& in) {
    return in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
...
if (in >> value0 >> ignl
    && in >> value1 >> ignl
    // ...
    ) {
    // do something with the result
}
```

Of course, the input always needs to be checked before it is used: otherwise random values will be processed in case of a failure.